# Probability exercise

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I have an exercise, where I now know the correct answer, but I just don't know how to get that result. This is the exercise:
[image]

I have tried using Bayes' Theorem, but I still cannot get the same result. Can you explain how it should be solved?

Comment: I would suggest following Ross Millikan's solution. It doesn't use Baye's Theorem, but I think it a more cleaner and easier solution to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d$ be the fraction of cars bought that are diesel.  The fraction that are petrol is then $1-d$ The fraction sold after three years is $$0.515(1-d)+0.2d=0.3\\0.215=0.315d$$